# unable to connect to Mongodb: Socket is closed

Tags: php, sockets, mongodb

I have the mongod up and running with the command- `sudo mongod --journal --rest --config /etc/mongodb.conf`, in the logs it says `waiting for connections on port 27017`

I am trying to connect to mongod from my PHP script using-
    $connection = new MongoClient($connectionString, $opts);

where `$connectionString = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017'`
and `$opts= array('replicaSet' => false, 'connect' => true);`

Irrespective of the $opts, i "often" get the exception-
`'MongoConnectionException' with message: Failed to connect to: 127.0.0.1:27017: send_package: error reading from socket: The socket is closed`

The last time I saw such error, I restarted mongod and the exception cleared off. But now it has stuck up again. Sometimes refreshing the browser does the trick. Any clues as to why such undependable behavior??

Thanks.

Comment: It suddenly started working without any change. Is this related to the socket being busy or unavailable ? Or is it something with mongod ?
I still need an explanation to the situation, so that i can avoid future breakdowns.

Comment: Best guess is that multiple processes are trying to use port 27017.  Try connecting to the database with mongo command line to eliminate the driver as a source of problems.

Comment: Edited question coz $opts['persist']=>true does not make sense when using MongoClient (coz all connections are persistent as opposed to plain Mongo)

Comment: Based on your URI and options, you may as well not pass any arguments to the [MongoClient constructor](http://php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php). Once this exception starts appearing, and before you restart mongod to fix it, are you able to connect via the mongo shell or other drivers?

Comment: will have to wait for the next time this happens

Answer (score 0):

I'm using symfony2 to connect to MongoDB and when i deleted the port from options list it works !

Try it